# What are the equations for motion with constant jerk?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, jerk

Every one knows the three famous **equations for motions with constant acceleration** . But what if the motion were having a jerk? How should then be the equations for motions?  How can I find them?

Comment: Have a look at this hyperphysics webpage: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/avari.html

Comment: Aren't there four...

Comment: See the derivations for the equations of motion for _constant acceleration_ and _constant jerk_ in this excellent article too: The Physics
Hypertextbook: Kinematics and Calculus: https://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's no different than any other case with a general time dependence of acceleration. You just need to know that acceleration is the rate of velocity change: $a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ and velocity is the rate of position change $v= \dfrac{dx}{dt}$. Integrate twice and you get

$$v=v_0+\int_0^{t} a(\tau)d\tau$$
$$x=x_0+\int_0^t v(\tau)d\tau$$

For constant $a$, this just gives $v=v_0+at$ and $x=x_0+v_0 t + \frac12 at^2$.

Jerk is defined analogously to the previous two kinematic relations, $j=\dfrac{da}{dt}$. If it's constant, just integrate once to get $a=a_0+jt$ and then twice more to get $v=v_0+a_0t+ \frac12 jt^2$ and $x=x_0+v_0t +\frac12 a_0 t^2+\frac16 j t^3$.

Comment: Sir, you are right in your points. But can you tell why you used definite integral? My book used indefinite integral.

Comment: If you write indefinite integral, you have to manually apply the initial conditions to find the integrating constant. In physics, it's really easy to write integral bounds, because they directly relate to initial conditions. In this case, the velocity goes from $v_0$ to the current velocity $v$, when time goes from $0$ to current time $t$ (it's common to set the origin of time to $0$). In physics, we sometimes don't write the limits and we still know from the context that we mean a definite integral. Also, the book probably just wanted to hint to the procedure, not apply it to an example.

Comment: Then sir, you ought to answer [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147779) . I will be very grateful.

Comment: And sir, what you have written is nothing but indefinite integral because it has variable upper limit. You can see Richard Courant's statement regarding this and also Fundamentamental theorem of Calculus 1 . Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. It's the same thing but knowing the lower limit tells you exactly what the integrating constant is. It's the same math, but it's easier to understand and work with if you explicitly put in the initial condition. I responded in your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness if you have non-constant acceleration then the motion can be described using the following three scenarios:

- **Acceleration is a function of time** - Given $a(t)$, then direct integration provides

  $$\begin{aligned}
    v(t) &= v_0 + \int_{t_0}^t a(t)\,{\rm d}t \\
    x(t) &= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t v(t)\,{\rm d}t \\
  \end{aligned}$$

  This is the scenario where acceleration has constant jerk $a(t) = a_0 + j\, t$
- **Acceleration is a function of speed** - Given $a(v)$, then direct integration provides expressions for distance as a function of speed, and time as a function of speed

  $$\begin{aligned}
    t(v) &= t_0 + \int_{v_0}^v \frac{1}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v \\
    x(v) &= x_0 + \int_{v_0}^v \frac{v}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v \\
  \end{aligned}$$
- **Acceleration is a function of distance** - Given $a(x)$, then direct integration provides expressions for speed as a function of distance, and time as a function of distance

  $$\begin{aligned}
    \tfrac{1}{2} v(x)^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} v_0^2 &= \int_{x_0}^x a(x)\,{\rm d}x \\
    t(v) &= t_0 + \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{v(x)}\,{\rm d}x \\
  \end{aligned}$$